# Obter Código Fonte Firefox DLL DDEClient

Tags: delphi

Sei que é possível capturar a URL do FIREFOX usando o DDEClient, mais alguém já usou o mesmo para obter o código fonte da página aberta ?

Segue o código para capturar o título:

```
procedure TForm1.GetCurrentURL(var sURL: String; var sTitle: String; var sSource: String);
var
DDEClient : TDDEClientConv;
s : String;
begin
s := '';
try
DDEClient := TDDEClientConv.Create(self);
with DDEClient do
begin
if SetLink('IExplore','WWW_GetWindowInfo') then
begin
s := RequestData('0xFFFFFFFF, sURL, sTitle');
sSource := 'Source: IE';
end
else
if SetLink('Netscape','WWW_GetWindowInfo') then
begin
s := RequestData('0xFFFFFFFF, sURL, sTitle');
sSource := 'Source: IE';
end
else
if SetLink('Mosaic','WWW_GetWindowInfo') then
begin
s := RequestData('0xFFFFFFFF, sURL, sTitle');
sSource := 'Source: Mosaic';
end
else
if SetLink('Chrome','WWW_GetWindowInfo') then
begin
s := RequestData('0xFFFFFFFF, sURL, sTitle');
sSource := 'Source: Netscape 6';
end
else
if SetLink('Mozilla','WWW_GetWindowInfo') then
begin
s := RequestData('0xFFFFFFFF, sURL, sTitle');
sSource := 'Source: Mozilla';
end
else
if SetLink('Firefox','WWW_GetWindowInfo') then
begin
s := RequestData('0xFFFFFFFF, sURL, sTitle, sSource');
sSource := 'Source: FireFox';
end;
end;
if s <> '' then
begin
Delete(s, 1, 1);
sURL := 'URL: ' +Copy(s, 1, pos('","',s)-1);
Delete(s, 1, Pos('","', s)+2);
sTitle := 'Title: ' +Copy(s, 1, Pos('"', s) - 1);
end;
exit;
except
MessageDlg('URL attempt failed!',mtError,[mbOK],0);
end;
end;
```

Para Usar:

```
  procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
sURL, sTitle, sSource: String;
begin
GetCurrentURL(sURL, sTitle, sSource);
Memo1.Lines.Add(sURL);
Memo1.Lines.Add(sTitle);
Memo1.Lines.Add(sSource);
end;
```

Comment: rapaz, [pare de usar DDE](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/02/26/1763683.aspx) ;)

Comment: @EMBarbosa, ainda assim não achei a solução para capturar o fonte do firefox pelo delphi rsrsrs..

Comment: Do modo como a pergunta foi feita ficou parecendo que você está querendo "espionar" o que o usuário está fazendo ao navegar. Acho que será difícil alguém querer lhe ajudar. NO entanto, você poderia usar um componente como o TWebBrowser para que o usuário navegasse em sua aplicação. O caso seria diferente...

Comment: Não é isso @EMBarbosa, se fosse pra isso, usaria vários softwares prontos a venda da internet e não perderia tempo com isso, é que estou fazendo um sistema de propaganda, e só consegui fazer funcionar no IE, no FIREFOX não consegui. Apenas isso. Atualizei a resposta, veja.

Answer (score 1):

Se você já tem a URL, para pegar o fonte faça o seguinte:

1. Adicione um `idHttp` ao `Form`;
2. Adicione um `Memo` ao `Form`;
3. Execute o seguinte:

```delphi
Memo1.text :=   IdHTTP1.Get('URL DESEJADA');
```

Seu fonte estará no `Memo`.

Comment: não tenho a URL, vai ser a URL que estiver aberta no navegado mozilla. Por isso preciso trabalhar com o DDEClient.

Comment: Certo, você perguntou como pegar o fonte, porque a URL você sabia pegar. Se você quiser edito a resposta com a função para [capturar a url também pelo DDEClient](http://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/torry/showcode.php?id=198).

Comment: Mas só vi isso funcionando de fato no IE. A premissa é que você havia conseguido fazer funcionar no firefox. :)

Comment: Será que não é possível fazer no firefox pelo DDEClient @Filipe.Fonseca ? Sei que o título do FIREFOX é possível capturar pelo DDEClient.

Comment: Poste essa função que pega o título que eu tento adaptar pra você.

Comment: atualizei a resposta, veja....espero que consiga me ajudar!

Comment: conseguiu fazer algo ?

Comment: @user7605 com a rotina você obtém a URL, com a URL você consegue pelo método que te passei pegar o fonte!

Comment: qualquer página que eu coloco no endereço do GET até mesmo globo.com, ou google.com.br, ele da erro Forbiden, porque será ?

Comment: Já resolvi @Filipe.Fonseca, obrigado!

Comment: Você conseguiu resolver? Poderia colocar uma resposta para que outras pessoas possam ser ajudadas?